# SQL Server : CASE statement inside stuff function

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use `case` statement inside stuff function with `for xml path()` ?

Comment: Have you bothered to try it?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **NOT** a statement! It's an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns exactly one atomic value (from a set of possible values)

Comment: Yes I am trying Case expression in Stuff function. As I am new to SQL server, I don't know it is  possible or not

Comment: The best way to find out is by trying it. And if you need help you need to provide details of your question so other can help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a 'CASE`statement inside`STUFF`when using`FOR XML PATH`

```
SELECT STUFF('alpha',3,5,CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END) FOR XML PATH('test')
```